# Tomcat Check Server Status - command, No found, start command

Tags: tomcat

**Question 1: Command for Check Status**

May I know if there is any command method to call for Check Server Status such in the:

`http://localhost:8080/manager/status?`

- If the installed server is non-GUI, how you guys check Status example Total Memory.

I already googling but still cannot found it.

**Question 2: What reason Not Found Check Server Status.**

1 tomcat duplicate 2 which called tomcat1 and tomcat2
I encounter a problem when I click the Check Server Status using `http://localhost:8080/manager2/status`, it goes

Not Found
The requested URL /manager2/status was not found on this server.

May I know where is manager2/status?

NOTE: Tomcat1 working accordingly.

**Question 3: Tomcat Start command**

All start tomcat method

1. /etc/init.d/tomcat start
2. /var/lib/tomcat2/bin/startup.sh
3. /var/lib/tomcat2/bin/catalina.sh

Can anyone tell me what different between them?

Answer (score 1):

I'm looking for Question 1 too.. But there is no such thing "Check Server Status from Command Line" at Tomcat.

I didn't understand Question 2 actually. But if you want to create duplicate tomcat instances at the same time. You must change ports from "conf/server.xml"

First instance:
http://localhost:8080/manager/status

Second instance:
http://localhost:8081/manager/status

Like this.

Question 3:

```
/etc/init.d/tomcat start
```

This is a case start. You can stop or restart tomcat instance by typing /etc/init.d/tomcat stop or restart.

```
/var/lib/tomcat2/bin/startup.sh
```

Its a trigger for catalina.sh, you don't have to use this one. Its checking system, if catalina already running, it does nothing.

```
/var/lib/tomcat2/bin/catalina.sh
```

This is direct execution for Tomcat.

I prefer the case start. Seems more true.

Answer (score 1):

Possible solution (though not very convenient) to question 1 can be found on [Tomcat HOWTO page](http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/HowTo#How_do_I_check_whether_Tomcat_is_UP_or_DOWN.3F_There_is_no_status_command)

Hope this helps...

Answer (score 0):

Well, sorry I did not follow you on the 1 and 2 questions. But for the 3 question following are the differences/ multiple ways or starting/ running `tomcat`.

```
./catalina.sh run
```

Passing "run" argument for catalina.sh --> starts the Tomcat in the **foreground** and **displays the running logs in the same console**. when the console terminal is closed it **will terminate the tomcat**.

```
./catalina.sh start
```

Passing "start" argument for catalina.sh --> starts the **Tomcat in the background**. Since in background no issues closing down the terminal. The logs need to be viewed as below: `tail -f $CATALINA_HOME/logs/catalina.out`

```
./startup.sh
```

The last way is firing the startup.sh to start your Tomcat server. If you Vi the script you can see it calls **catalina.sh script passing start as the argument**. This will be running in background as well.